# Quiet install not running

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Just wanted to see if anyone had any idea why this won't run in Powershell. It will run without the quiet flag, but won't run with it. Bare with me, I am no scriptwriter.

```
Write-Host "Checking Execution policy"

$policy = Get-ExecutionPolicy

        if ($policy -ne "Unrestricted")

{

        Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

}
        Write-Host "Adding ODBC Connection FisFMIS"

        # Windows PowerShell example to check 'If File Exists'
            $ChkFile = "C:\Windows\System32\msodbcsql17.dll"
            $FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile

            For ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
 {

                If ($FileExists -eq $True) 

{
          # Configure Odbc connection for FisFMIS

                Add-OdbcDsn -DriverName "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" -DsnType User -Name fisFMIS -AsJob -SetPropertyValue ("Server=FSC-FMAP-BE01.univ.pitt.edu", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=FISFMIS")
}
           # Odbc driver is not installed, install the driver

                    Else 

             {msiexec.exe /i "\\univ.pitt.edu\fis-dfs\Deploy$\Sources\Software\Jobs\msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
}

                    Start-Sleep -s 100




}
```

Comment: Check your msilog.log for errors.  When you run the installer without the /QN switch do you get any User Access Control popups?  If your installer requires elevated privileges and you are not running as admin this is likely the reason for it not completing when trying to run quietly.

Comment: I am testing on my own device that I have admin rights. Shouldn't it run?

Comment: If UAC is turned on having admin rights and running a process as admin are not the same.  Being an administrator affords you the ability to run applications as administrator however you have to explicitly run the application as administrator or a UAC prompt "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?" with Yes/No option.  If Yes is not selected the application will not run.  You can use `Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i ""\\univ.pitt.edu\fis-dfs\Deploy$\Sources\Software\Jobs\msodbcsql_17.4.2.1_x64.msi""", "/QN", "/l*v ""C:\msilog.log""" -Verb RunAs`

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the Start-Process powershell command when launching installs since I'm usually waiting for them to complete before continuing with my Powershell script. Check out [this site](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-21-powershell-installing-msi-files/) for a great example...with logging.